# Android 8: USB connection now drains the battery, instead of charging it

Tags: nexus-5x, 8.0-oreo

Ever since I updated to Android 8 on my Nexus 5X the USB connection drains the battery, instead of charging it. I have tried it with my laptop, my workstation at the office and another computer, and the result is always the same.

The picture below shows the battery charge graph. After 2 hours and an half connected through USB to the computer the battery went from about 20% to 7%. I have no applications running, turned off the WiFi and the mobile data.

[image]

Why has Android 8 changed the behaviour of the USB connection? Is there any way of reversing it?

Comment: This is most likely a cable or charger issue... Or less likely a bad USB port on the device. Try a known good cable and charger and boot into safe mode.

Comment: @acejavelin I am using the same cable with which I have been recharging this device for over an year. As I wrote in the question, I have tried it in different computers and USB ports.